# Entropy of a set of strings based on a sample

Tags: distributions, entropy, information-theory, string-count

Say I have an enormous set of N-character-long strings. Far too many to enumerate or store in memory, but far fewer than the theoretical $26^N$ possible strings. I can draw samples from this set, but it's slightly computationally expensive: I can probably get thousands of samples, but not millions.

I'm looking to get an estimate of how many unique strings are in this set, and I'm wondering if entropy or entropy estimation would be useful.

Intuitively, if I draw 2 random samples and they are:

- `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog`
- `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazycat`

... then it's likely there's far fewer unique values than if I had gotten:

- `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog`
- `sdklfkaimrgkmcepoaksmfpaklsmfptinkd`

How can I make this intuition more rigorous?

## Update

More information was requested in a comment.

Concretely, I'm working on a crossword construction program. I have a blank crossword grid, a dictionary of words, and a set of requirements from the constructor about how the  grid ought to be filled in (e.g. "this clue must have one of these words" or "no clue can use that word."). I'm looking to quantify how stringent those requirements are, thereby providing a signal like, "this requirement brought the estimated number of possible completed grids from ~2^40 down to ~2^10." (In my head I've been saying: "this requirement has 30 bits of information," hence the connection to entropy.)

The constructor's requirements define a set of valid crossword puzzles that meet those requirements. I can draw samples from that set by running a randomized search algorithm to fill in the grid, but doing so is somewhat expensive.

Again, the intuition is that if I generate 1,000 samples and they all look very similar, probably there aren't that many valid solutions given the current constraints. But if each sample looks radically different from each other sample, then likely there are many unique solutions. That's a heuristic argument, but it feels reasonable to me.

Comment: What is your basis for concluding "it's likely there's far fewer"?  There is no information in your post that would support this implication.

Comment: In the first pair, the vast majority of the letters are the same. If the underlying distribution uniformly spanned the space of N-character strings, that'd be extremely unlikely.

Comment: That's not relevant when it comes to your question, though: it has nothing to do with either uniqueness or entropy.  It sounds like there's more to your situation than you have yet shared with us.  Please consider elaborating on your question.

Comment: Added more context. Does that help?